# How do I run a script every time "yum update" is run?

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, yum

I'd like to run a script (let's say myScript.sh) every time a `yum update` or `yum install` command is executed.

So if I run `yum update someprogram` then `myScript.sh` should be executed right after that. Is this possible?

Currently I could run a script if I put it in the ".spec" file when I build the rpm to install, but we have a lot of packages and I'd like to have this script run everytime any package gets updated. I thought about maybe using a cron job to run it every hour but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/WritingYumPlugins

Comment: See this answer on [Yum post actions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585786/161288). You basically write a small actions file that matches specific packages, general actions, or both, and you point it to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create bash function in `.bashrc` :

```
myyumfunction() {
    yum update $1
    myScript.sh
}
```

Bash functions that you define in your `.bashrc` are available within your shell. You can call your function like this:

```
$ myyumfunction someprogram
```

Comment: This covers the manual call to yum but not things like automatique updates or calls to yum via GUIs for example. +1 anyway because it's a simple and good solution.

Comment: Thanks @shcherbak! It would be difficult for me to try to get other people to use my custom function, but this isn't a bad idea! I might end up having to do this.